# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807) ios 10 for self signed certificate on web socket

Tags: ios10

The iOS app has a web application and being rendered on UIWebView. The web application is connecting via web socket. On iOS 9 and below, the web socket connection is working fine but not for iOS 10.

Getting this error:

> CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)